# How do you search for a string in a webpage with javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, greasemonkey

I am making a javascript greasemonkey script that redirects you when it finds a certain string in a webpage. Here is my code:

```
// ==UserScript==<br>
// @name No 009 Sound System!<br>
// @version 1.0<br>
// @namespace http://www.cakeman.biz/<br>
// @description Warn user when about to view a youtube video with 009 Sound System audio<br>
// @include http://*/*<br>
// @copyright  2011+, Zack Marotta 
// ==/UserScript==

var result, search_term = 'somerandomsearchterm';
var str = document.URL;
var url_check = str.search(search_term);
if (url_check !== -1) {
var result = search_term;
alert(str);
    window.location = "http://www.web.site";
}
```

Nothing happens when the script runs. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Click here to view a list of your questions to accept them as Rob suggested. http://stackoverflow.com/users/940511/t3hcakeman

Comment: none of those answers worked though. haha

Comment: If "none of those answers worked", then go back and comment on the answers, and edit the questions -- explaining why the answers do not work for you.  The answers are good for the questions **as stated**; it's up to you to clarify when it's not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some specific functions, you have to use `unsafeWindow` instead of `window` in a Greasemonkey UserScript. If you want to get your script work at GreaseMonkey and other locations, use this:

```
var win = typeof unsafeWindow != "undefined" ? unsafeWindow : window;
```

---

I've shrinkened by original answer, because that seems not to be your issue. Most likely, you've forgot to add `// @include` to your meta block.

If your script has to redirect a certain, fixed page using GreaseMonkey, you can also shorten your scrip to:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Redirect
// @include *i-am-afraid-of-this-word*
// ==/UserScript==

location.href = "http://www.google.com/search?q=need-help-getting-courage";
```

For more information about the meta block, see: http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_block

Comment: didn't work. are you sure it is `url_check != -1` instead of `url_check !== -1`?

Comment: Yes. Are you sure that your GM script is active at your page, by including `// @include *`? *Replace `*` by a more specific selector.* Note that your script can also be shortened to: `// ==UserScript== //@include *somerandomsearchterm* // ==/UserScript== unsafeWindow.location.href="http://www.web.site";`

Comment: the shortening thing did not work. I'll add my meta to the script.

Comment: Is there any way I can contact you or something?

Comment: Yes, open a chatroom at http://chat.stackoverflow.com, and invite me. What exactely doesn't work? What error messages did you get?

Answer (score 0):

You notice that you're performing a Case-Sensitive search? it would not trigger if just one letter is capital when looking for a lower-case, or vice versa, if you want a case-Insensitive you need a RegExp as your "search-term".

Other thing is, you don't need `<br>` in the metadata block, because then the include is the one not working, otherwise the page would need to have `<br>` in the address to match and execute.

Extra: The !== should work just fine, but it's not needed, in this case a != would do, and it is strongly recommended that you don't use unsafeWindow.